# How to go back to ViewContoller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am making app for iOS and using Swift. When I open WebViewController from ViewController it works fine but the problem occurred when I click on the back button in the navigation bar to go back to ViewContoller. Then I get this error:

> Inspection is enabled by default for process or parent application
> with 'get-task-allow' entitlement linked against old SDK. Use
> `inspectable` API to enable inspection on newer SDKs. 2023-09-25
> 09:24:14.668225+0530 all in one tools[11108:2951385]
> -[GUL_all_in_one_tools.AppDelegate-EFDEC20C-4D84-4E03-99AF-EE650765ECFE
> window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2811c0de0 2023-09-25
> 09:24:14.670287+0530 all in one tools[11108:2951385] *** Terminating
> app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
> '-[GUL_all_in_one_tools.AppDelegate-EFDEC20C-4D84-4E03-99AF-EE650765ECFE
> window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2811c0de0'
> *** First throw call stack: (0x1c22dd48c 0x1bb5bd050 0x1c243e424 0x1c4f07514 0x1c22f2700 0x1c235497c 0x10390d7bc 0x103c597a0
> 0x103c5b0e8 0x10390d734 0x10390f4dc 0x10390f3f4 0x102f6e380
> 0x102f6e3c4 0x1c427a9fc 0x1c469ff7c 0x1c4475744 0x1c43ac974
> 0x1c4453dbc 0x1c450000c 0x1c4a04d68 0x1c51cbfcc 0x1c433370c
> 0x1c43326c0 0x1c4331ecc 0x1c4331fcc 0x1c37819ec 0x103c597a0
> 0x103c6834c 0x103c67fa4 0x1c2365a2c 0x1c23496c8 0x1c234dda0
> 0x1f96bc998 0x1c45df80c 0x1c45df484 0x1ca561ddc 0x102f6ad4c
> 0x102f6acd4 0x102f6add0 0x1dfafc344) libc++abi: terminating due to
> uncaught exception of type NSException
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
> '-[GUL_all_in_one_tools.AppDelegate-EFDEC20C-4D84-4E03-99AF-EE650765ECFE
> window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2811c0de0'
> terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException

[image]

This is how I open WebViewController from ViewController

```
@IBAction func flipTextBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    let ViewController:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let desVC = ViewController.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WebViewController") as! WebViewController
                                
    desVC.Title = "Title Here"
           
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(desVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with more details about the error. Please show the complete error and point out exactly which line of code the error happens on.

Comment: i have updated the question please take a look thanks @HangarRash

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController is not right method to use for go back.
```

**For go back, you just need to write below line**

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

If you want to go back to a specific UIViewController, then first of all, you need to find a particular UIViewController from the current navigation stack, and after getting a particular UIViewController, you can go back.

**Here is the example of how to go back to specific UIViewController**

```
guard let vc = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.filter({$0.isKind(of: WebViewController.self)}).first else {return}//get the specific vc
self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score -1):

i found the solution , just added

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

in AppDelegate and it works..

thanks for help :)